# Trigger event that was bound in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

In one file, I have:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', resizeMap, false);
```

and in another file, I have:

```
$(window).triggerHandler('focus');
```

but it doesn't call the `resizeMap` function I attached in the first file.  Is there something I'm missing on how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `triggerHandler` event won't fire events bound natively.  If you use `$window.on` instead, you'll get your desired behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/zowsdo5z/

vs

http://jsfiddle.net/zowsdo5z/1/